# Extracting information from SGM files using Python

Tags: python, parsing, extract, sgml

I need some help for extracting information out of an .sgm file using Python. Is there a specific library suitable for this specific kind of file? Or will libraries used to extract infos from .xml files work as well? If there are no libraries available, can you please suggest me a good module I can download to work with .sgm files?

And above all, if any, can you please explain me the difference between an .xml and a .sgm file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few libraries which can be used to parse .sgm files:

- [SGMLtools-lite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sgmltools-lite/)
- [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup)

The major difference between the two is that SGML permits the following:

> Unclosed start-tags
>
> Unclosed end-tags
>
> Empty start-tags
>
> Empty end-tags

**References**

- [Comparison of SGML and XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-sgml-xml)